# Key combination not working when using the touch bar?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, touch-bar

In an IDE I use key combinations like <kbd>Shift</kbd>shift <kbd>⎋</kbd> (<kbd>Esc</kbd>).

I'm now using a MacBook Pro with a Touch Bar. It seems this is not working anymore, as the IDE only reports <kbd>Esc</kbd> being pressed.

Has anyone else experienced this?

PS: I've heard about the workaround of mapping caps lock to <kbd>Esc</kbd>, but I'd like to use that as a last resort.

- https://discussions.apple.com/message/31347902#31347902
- https://discussions.apple.com/message/31206769#31206769

Answer (score 1):

Try hitting <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>, that triggers the Shift+Esc for me. If you press the left shift key with your left thumb, it is a very similar gesture.

Comment: Thx, but doesn't seem to work